# How to stop animation in random button text, codenameone?

Tags: java, codenameone

I want to stop any component text animation.

For Ex:

Setting text on selection as below

```
final Button statusButton = new Button("Select Status");
final CheckBox inProcessButton = new CheckBox("In-Progress");
inProcessButton.setUIID("filter_combo_label");
inProcessButton.setName(Constants.STATUS_ACTIVE_NONCOMPLETE);
radioButtonGroup.add(inProcessButton);
inProcessButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
        String checkBoxVal = ComponentUtils.getCSMultiCheckValues(radioButtonGroup);
        statusButton.setText(checkBoxVal);
        statusButton.repaint();
    }
});
```

See snapshot as below.

Before selection:

[image]

After selection label image animating.

[image]
[image]

Comment: The answer from @Diamond is correct but I think the real question is: what is your layout? By giving the button more room, animation wouldn't happen in the first place. I'm guessing you used `FlowLayout` try using BorderLayout and place the button in the center and the status in the east.

Comment: @Shai- Yes that's true. I have to use border layout instead of using flow layout. thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do `statusButton.setTickerEnabled(false);`. This will prevent tickering the button text.

You might also want to end long texts with 3 dots:

```
statusButton.setEndsWith3Points(true);
```